# I have six images and six extracts of text, I want two images per row with the relevant text centred underneath

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I'm working on a page on a website and getting slightly stuck with how I'm going to position these images and their relevant text underneath. It sounds simple enough but I seem to be having a lot of trouble positioning with CSS lately, its the one thing I can't seem to get my head around.

[Example screenshot of what I've got so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDoxg.png)

And here's my relevant CSS:

```
.core-value {
display: inline;
}

.img-circle {
border-radius: 50%;
width: 15%;
}

.core-value-text {
text-align: center;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="core-value">
<img class="img-circle" src="Long_Term_Relationships.jpg">              
<div class="core-value-text">
<h4>Forging Strong Long Term Relationships</h4>
<p>We focus on strong, long term relationships with our clients</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="core-value">
<img class="img-circle" src="focus.jpg">    
<div class="core-value-text">
<h4>Focus</h4>
<p>We focus on understanding our clients' long term strategies</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="core-value">
<img class="img-circle" src="Team.jpg"> 
<div class="core-value-text">
<h4>A Clear Sense of Team</h4>
<p>We work closely as a team, irrespective of our diverse work</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="core-value">
<img class="img-circle" src="integrity.jpg">    
<div class="core-value-text">
<h4>Intergrity</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="core-value">
<img class="img-circle" src="excellence.jpg">   
<div class="core-value-text">
<h4>Excellence</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="core-value">
<img class="img-circle" src="delivery.jpg"> 
<div class="core-value-text">
<h4>Delivery</h4>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help on how to to do this would be greatly appreciated, looking to learn not just get an answer so an explanation why your code did what I wanted it to do would be appreciated also. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.core-value {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  /* 50% to get two columns  */
  float: left;
  /* to keep the elements in one row*/
}
.core-value:nth-child(2n+1) {
  clear: both;
  /* to drop the float, incase height of image or content causes float issue */
}
.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*align image to center*/
}
.core-value-text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="core-value">
  <img class="img-circle" src="Long_Term_Relationships.jpg">
  <div class="core-value-text">
    <h4>Forging Strong Long Term Relationships</h4>
    <p>We focus on strong, long term relationships with our clients</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="core-value">
  <img class="img-circle" src="focus.jpg">
  <div class="core-value-text">
    <h4>Focus</h4>
    <p>We focus on understanding our clients' long term strategies</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="core-value">
  <img class="img-circle" src="Team.jpg">
  <div class="core-value-text">
    <h4>A Clear Sense of Team</h4>
    <p>We work closely as a team, irrespective of our diverse work</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="core-value">
  <img class="img-circle" src="integrity.jpg">
  <div class="core-value-text">
    <h4>Intergrity</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="core-value">
  <img class="img-circle" src="excellence.jpg">
  <div class="core-value-text">
    <h4>Excellence</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="core-value">
  <img class="img-circle" src="delivery.jpg">
  <div class="core-value-text">
    <h4>Delivery</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this you have to .core-value widht 50% and float left then 2 contianers comes in one line

```
.core-value {
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your css as the code shown below and give it a try:

```
.core-value {
text-align:center;
}

.img-circle {
border-radius: 50%;
width: 15%;
}
```

now if you want to put like 2 divs in a row,use the code below:

```
 .core-value {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    width 50%;
    }

    .img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 15%;
    }
```

now if you want 3 divs in a row,i hope you got the concept you give .core-value a width of 100/3=33.33% and float them to the left. now what the text-align:center does is format the elements(both images and texts) inside of div core-value to be aligned at the center of the div.

Comment: So .core-value-text as a div isn't actually needed and I could just keep the text in the same div as a image?

Comment: it depends on what your final result is going to be,or what you are trying to achieve here,for simple puropse like this once,you won't need that div